# Format number - Prefer annotated tokens (like `%<foo>s`) over unannotated tokens (like `%s`) (Rubocop)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I have this line of code which Rubocop is complaining about

```
offset = -7
format('%.2i', offset)
```

Rubocop's message is

> rubocop: warning
>   C - Style/FormatStringToken: Prefer annotated tokens (like `%<foo>s`) over unannotated tokens (like `%s`).

But even when reading the explanations in the documentation https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/FormatStringToken I cannot make it compliant.

The goal of the code is to add a 0 whenever the `offset` is a single digit number and to not add anything when the number has two digits already.

I tried the following:

```
offset = -7
format('%.2{offset}', offset: offset)
```

Comment: It looks like you ommitted the `i` after the precision and token name. Add it back in, like this: `format('%.2{offset}i', ..`

Comment: That doesn't work for me, it prints: `"2i"`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To specify styles, you have to use `<offset>`, not `{offset}`. The correct syntax is:

```
format('%<offset>.2i', offset: offset)
#=> "-07"
```

The `<variable_name>` part goes *between* `%` and `.2i`.